# ¿Como puedo extraer e imprimir un dato de un lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cuando estaba tratando de realizar un ejercicio me encontré con el problema de la impresión de una lista, donde mi principal intención era imprimir un dato de una lista, luego de otra y así con todas las listas que tenia, pero al momento de ejecutar el programa los datos de salida son solo del elemento 0  de la lista y los  muestra doble vez.

Como deseo que se imprima:

1. El nombre del alumno es: Juan
2. Calificación del primer parcial:    10
3. Calificación del primer parcial:    8
4. Calificación del primer parcial:    9
5. Promedio final:   9

Y así que imprima primero los datos de un alumno y luego con otro hasta llegar a los 5 alumnos.

Pero al ejecutar el programa me queda de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les comparto mi codigo completo:

```
numero = 5
numero1 = 5
listanombres = []
lista_cal_1 = []
lista_cal_2 = []
lista_cal_3 = []
lista_promedios = []


while numero > 0:
   nombres = input(("Introduzca el nombre del alumno: \n"))
   listanombres.append(nombres)
   cal_1 = int(input("Introduzca la calificacion 1: \n"))
   lista_cal_1.append(cal_1)
   cal_2 = int(input("Introduzca la calificacion 2: \n"))
   lista_cal_2.append(cal_2)
   cal_3 = int(input("Introduzca la calificacion 3: \n"))
   lista_cal_3.append((cal_3))

   promedios = (cal_1+cal_2+cal_3)/3
   lista_promedios.append(promedios)

   numero -= 1


while numero1 > 0:

   i = 0
   for x in listanombres:
      print("El nombre del alumno es: ")
      print(listanombres[i])


  for x in lista_cal_1:
      print("Calificacion del primer parcial:")
      print(lista_cal_1[i])


  for x in lista_cal_2:
      print("Calificacion del segundo parcial: ")
      print(lista_cal_2[i])

  for x in lista_cal_3:
      print("Calificacion del tercer parcial: ")
      print(lista_cal_3[i])

  for x in lista_promedios:
      print("El promedio final es:  ")
      print(lista_promedios[i])

  i += 1
  numero1 -= 1
```

Aun soy principiante en la programación, llevo mucho tiempo tratando de solucionar esto pero no encontré ninguna solución, seria de mucha ayuda si me pudieran apoyar, hoy es mi primer día con este lenguaje y mi primera publicación en el foro :),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón por la cual retorna siempre el valor del índice 0 de la lista se debe a que defines **i = 0** al inicio del bucle *while*, por lo tanto aunque le sumes uno al final, cuando el bucle inicia nuevamente, la variable i vuelve a valer 0.
Por otro lado, el mismo alumno se repite 5 veces debido al bucle *for*. Por ejemplo: para x en listanombres, listanombres tiene 5 valores, pero siempre se ejecuta el de índice i (i no cambia hasta el final del bucle). La forma en la que funcionaría correctamente es la siguiente:

```
  numero = 5
  numero1 = 5
  listanombres = []
  lista_cal_1 = []
  lista_cal_2 = []
  lista_cal_3 = []
  lista_promedios = []


  while numero > 0:
     nombres = input("Introduzca el nombre del alumno: \n")
     listanombres.append(nombres)
     cal_1 = int(input("Introduzca la calificacion 1: \n"))
     lista_cal_1.append(cal_1)
     cal_2 = int(input("Introduzca la calificacion 2: \n"))
     lista_cal_2.append(cal_2)
     cal_3 = int(input("Introduzca la calificacion 3: \n"))
     lista_cal_3.append(cal_3)

     promedios = (cal_1+cal_2+cal_3)/3
     lista_promedios.append(promedios)

     numero -= 1

  i = 0 #Defines i antes del bucle y fuera de este.
  while numero1 > 0:

     #Los bucles for no están más.
     print("El nombre del alumno es: ")
     print(listanombres[i])

     print("Calificacion del primer parcial:")
     print(lista_cal_1[i])

     print("Calificacion del segundo parcial: ")
     print(lista_cal_2[i])

     print("Calificacion del tercer parcial: ")
     print(lista_cal_3[i])

     print("El promedio final es:  ")
     print(lista_promedios[i])

     i += 1
     numero1 -= 1
```

Espero se entienda y te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Te entendí perfectamente, si era eso, muchas gracias por responder :)